# mongodB: MapReduce internal error Size of emitted values exceeds the set size limit of 104857600 bytes

Tags: mongodb

i'm new to MongoDB world.
When i'm trying to make a map_recude i get this error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: MapReduce internal error :: caused by :: Size of emitted values exceeds the set size limit of 104857600 bytes : , full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'MapReduce internal error :: caused by :: Size of emitted values exceeds the set size limit of 104857600 bytes :\n@:6:29\n@:5:21\n', 'code': 31292, 'codeName': 'Location31292'}
```

Any idea on how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That means that the total size of all the key-value pairs passed to `emit` for a single input document exceeds 100MB.

The only real fix is to emit fewer or smaller documents so the size limit is not exceeded.